# Is there a nonzero module $M$ over an artinian local ring $(R,\mathfrak m)$ such that $\mathfrak mM=M\ ?$

Tags: commutative-algebra, local-rings, artinian

Let me paste the title:

Is there a nonzero module $M$ over an artinian local ring $(R,\mathfrak m)$ such that $\mathfrak mM=M\ ?$

Of course such a module could *not* be finitely generated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such a nonzero module doesn't exist. If $(R,\mathfrak{m})$ is an Artinian local ring, then $\mathfrak{m}$ is nilpotent. If $\mathfrak{m}M=M$, then $M=\mathfrak{m}M=\mathfrak{m}^2M=\dots=\mathfrak{m}^nM=0$.

More generally, if $R$ is an Artinian ring, denote by $r$ the radical of $R$. Then $r$ is nilpotent. For any module $M$, if $rM=M$, then $M=0$.